# Eloquent doesn't get the "belongsTo" item

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the Project model and the Contract model. When i execute Project:all() it gets me only the projects without the contract, same for contract. I tried to dd() inside contract and doesn't do anything, like is never executed. I also tried with App\ prefix and without.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Project extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'project';

    public function contract() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Contract');
    }
}

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Contract extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'contract';

    public function project() {
         return $this->hasMany('Project', 'ContractID', 'ContractID');
    }
}
```

I try to retrieve them like this:

```
$projects = Project::all()->take(10);
```

Comment: Could you also post the way you try to retrieve contracts or project?

Comment: @KA_lin please see the edit to the question

Comment: So you do a foreach loop on $projects and can't get $project->contract() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems here.

1. Project::all()->take(10);

This only returns a collection of projects. You havent specified that you want the contracts also.

```
$projects = Project::with('contract')->get();
```

2. In your `belongsTo` - You havent specified the column that the table should join on. You need to do this, because you have not used a standard `id` for primary key and `contract_id` for foreign key.
3. unrelated to specific question, but your relationship in contract model is also wrong.

   `public function project() {
        return $this->hasMany('Project', 'ContractID', 'ContractID');
   }`

If one contract has many projects, then your `public function project()` should be `public function projects()`;

4. Finally - Why are you using non-standard table / column naming conventions? What's wrong with `contract_id`? Are you aware that mysql is non-case sensitive? Also the `project` table could be renamed `projects` and the `contract` table could be renamed `contracts`. It will make you writing your eloquent relations much easier and makes more sense!

If you used standard naming conventions, then you could just do this to declare your model relations.

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Contract extends Model
{
    public function projects() {
         return $this->hasMany('Project');
    }
}
```

Notice you dont need to specify the table name in the model, or how the table is related to the Project.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 1. Project::all()->take(10); i saw this on a tutorial from Codecourse here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xIBST5vVq84 . 3. You are correct. 4. The database already exists, the convention i use is for better readability, it's a matter of taste, but nothing to be done, as it is already in place. 2.I put the parameters of join.

Comment: And btw stored procedures are case sensitive :D